# Is there a way to return the URL of the first result of a google search in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, google-search-api

I'm developing a solution that requires the first result of a google search, specifically only the URL - I need to be able to break down the URL's path. Assuming the URL can be returned as a string i've got that covered.

Does anyone know of any libraries or otherwise that could help with this.

I've looked into the googleSearch API but I don't think it's what i'm looking for.

Thank you

Comment: the embedded `java.net.URL` has a `getText()` method. [Docs here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.2.0/html/groovy-jdk/java/net/URL.html). You can start from here, I'm sure that there are other more complex ways of achieving the same thing.